# On Firefox, my embedded Youtube videos don't display properly

Tags: video, youtube, embedding

I've embedded some YouTube videos in my fansite I'm developing. However, when you scroll through the webpage in Firefox, the divs and headers overlap the videos for some reason. Frankly, it just goes nuts. I opened the Error Console (although I really have no idea what to do with it) and it keeps giving me a JavaScript error. Is this what could cause it? In case someone else wants to see what I mean, view my website in FireFox. The URL is www.theguildwars2hq.com

The first picture is what it's supposed to look like, the second is what happens when you start scrolling.

I can't post images directly, so go here to view the images..

[What it looks like normally](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/8612/supposedtolooklike.png)

[What happens when you start scrolling](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/6501/notsupposedto.png)

Comment: I visited the site but did not see any errors. What exactly are you referring to? Also can you post screenshots? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the site and got this JavaScript error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.theguildwars2hq.com/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/CgYZk8Rkf3g. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

If that doesn't make anything jump out at you it is also possible that it has to do with your OS or browser, have you tried it on different systems or tried similar sites with you system?

Good luck!

Comment: Honestly, I am very clueless when it comes to JavaScript.. Very. I know nothing about it. I haven't tried it on another computer in FireFox, no. I'll test that out later/tomorrow. I wouldn't know how to fix anything pertaining to JavaScript, though. :/ It's just strange to me it only glitches out while in FireFox.

Comment: I have no problem with the latest firefox and WinXP in scrolling.

Comment: It looks as though the bad connections are in strange code not on your server and isn't your problem. I recommend you report it to google/ youtube if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Hm, well if it's not affecting anyone but me, I'm not too worried about it. Thanks for all the help, everyone.